# Creating a data frame with mean, standard deviation, standard error and confidence error

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new data frame with each variable's mean, standard deviation(sd), standard error(se) and confidence interval(ci) with this data frame.

```
pct.df <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), gender = c("male", 
"female", "male", "female", "male", "female"), var_a = c(33.3333333333333, 
16.6666666666667, 50, 50, 50, 33.3333333333333), var_b = c(50, 
75, 50, 75, 75, 75), var_c = c(50, 75, 75, 100, 75, 75), var_d = c(50, 
25, 0, 25, 50, 50), var_e = c(25, 0, 50, 0, 50, 25), var_f = c(25, 
25, 0, 50, 50, 25), var_g = c(25, 25, 0, 50, 50, 25), var_h = c(25, 
25, 0, 50, 50, 25), avg = c(35.4166666666667, 33.3333333333333, 
28.125, 50, 56.25, 41.6666666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I would like to compare group A and group B's mean for each variable (i.e. val_a to val_h and avg).

I currently know how to calculate the mean.

```
sum.df <- pct.df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -group, names_to = "Variable")
```

However, I am also trying to get the sd,se and ci of each var_ in the same data frame.

I tried my hand in using something like this from https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/4-barplot-with-error-bar.html to get what I want.

```
my_sum <- data %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise( 
    n=n(),
    mean=mean(Sepal.Length),
    sd=sd(Sepal.Length)
  ) %>%
  mutate( se=sd/sqrt(n))  %>%
  mutate( ic=se * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, n-1))
```

but I cant quite get it to work (due to the lack of understanding in how I should approach it with multiple variables). I am new to R and I would appreciate any advice or alternative methods I should look into.

Note- Ideally to an output that looks something like this?

```
    group Variables mean sd se  ci
1      a     var_a   38 16 22  54
2      a     var_b   69 24 45  93
3      a     var_c   75 20 55  95
4      a     var_d   44 12 32  56
5      a     var_e   31 24  7  55
6      a     var_f   38 14 24  52
7      a     var_g   38 14 24  52
8      a     var_h   38 14 24  52
9      a       AVG   46 14 32  60
10     b     var_a   58 29 29  87
11     b     var_b   81 12 69  93
12     b     var_c   88 14 74 102
13     b     var_d   56 31 25  87
14     b     var_e   56 31 25  87
15     b     var_f   56 31 25  87
16     b     var_g   56 31 25  87
17     b     var_h   56 31 25  87
18     b       AVG   64 25 39  89
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments and updated post, this solution will work:

```r
library(tidyverse)
pct.df <- structure(list(group = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), gender = c("male", 
                                                                             "female", "male", "female", "male", "female"), var_a = c(33.3333333333333, 
                                                                                                                                      16.6666666666667, 50, 50, 50, 33.3333333333333), var_b = c(50, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 75, 50, 75, 75, 75), var_c = c(50, 75, 75, 100, 75, 75), var_d = c(50, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    25, 0, 25, 50, 50), var_e = c(25, 0, 50, 0, 50, 25), var_f = c(25, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   25, 0, 50, 50, 25), var_g = c(25, 25, 0, 50, 50, 25), var_h = c(25, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   25, 0, 50, 50, 25), avg = c(35.4166666666667, 33.3333333333333, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               28.125, 50, 56.25, 41.6666666666667)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          -6L))
pct.df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(group, gender, avg), names_to = "variable") %>% 
  group_by(group, variable) %>%
  summarise(n = n(),
            mean = mean(value),
            sd = sd(value),
            se = sd/sqrt(n),
            ic = se * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, n-1)) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  bind_rows(summarise(., across(everything(),
                                ~if(is.numeric(.)) mean(.) else "AVG"))) %>%
  arrange(group)
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'group'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 18 x 6
#> # Groups:   group [2]
#>    group variable  mean    sd    se    ic
#>    <chr> <chr>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 a     var_a     33.3 16.7   9.62  41.4
#>  2 a     var_b     58.3 14.4   8.33  35.9
#>  3 a     var_c     66.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#>  4 a     var_d     25   25    14.4   62.1
#>  5 a     var_e     25   25    14.4   62.1
#>  6 a     var_f     16.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#>  7 a     var_g     16.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#>  8 a     var_h     16.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#>  9 a     AVG       32.3 17.4  10.0   43.1
#> 10 b     var_a     44.4  9.62  5.56  23.9
#> 11 b     var_b     75    0     0      0  
#> 12 b     var_c     83.3 14.4   8.33  35.9
#> 13 b     var_d     41.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#> 14 b     var_e     25   25    14.4   62.1
#> 15 b     var_f     41.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#> 16 b     var_g     41.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#> 17 b     var_h     41.7 14.4   8.33  35.9
#> 18 b     AVG       49.3 13.3   7.71  33.2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Close! However, I require group a and group b to be in the data frame.
This is because I am trying to find out how group A compares to group B in var_a to var_h and the "avg" (avg is the composite score of var_a and var_h).

I edited and added more specifics into the question (I should have been more specific and even provided an example - I apologise) . Thank you so much for your time in helping me out. Your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Thanks for updating your question - I have edited my answer to suit.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a similar method without pivoting the data.
this method relies on the fact that `summarise` can also return a vector of summarys.

```
pct.df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(
    val = c("mean", "sd", "n", "se", "ic"),
    across(
      where(is.numeric),
      ~c(mean(.x), sd(.x),length(.x), sd(.x) / length(.x), 
         sd(.x) / length(.x) * qt((1-0.05)/2 + .5, length(.x) - 1))
    ), .groups = "drop"
  )

# A tibble: 10 x 11
   group val   var_a var_b var_c var_d var_e var_f var_g var_h   avg
   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 a     mean  33.3  58.3  66.7  25    25    16.7  16.7  16.7  32.3 
 2 a     sd    16.7  14.4  14.4  25    25    14.4  14.4  14.4   3.76
 3 a     n      3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3   
 4 a     se     5.56  4.81  4.81  8.33  8.33  4.81  4.81  4.81  1.25
 5 a     ic    23.9  20.7  20.7  35.9  35.9  20.7  20.7  20.7   5.39
 6 b     mean  44.4  75    83.3  41.7  25    41.7  41.7  41.7  49.3 
 7 b     sd     9.62  0    14.4  14.4  25    14.4  14.4  14.4   7.32
 8 b     n      3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3     3   
 9 b     se     3.21  0     4.81  4.81  8.33  4.81  4.81  4.81  2.44
10 b     ic    13.8   0    20.7  20.7  35.9  20.7  20.7  20.7  10.5
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for helping me out. I was wondering if it is possible to have the data frame to look like the sample output? (I just edited and added more specifics to the question. In hindsight, I should have done that first, apologies).

Comment: the best way to do that would be to use Jared_mamrot's solution with an additional `group_by(group)`.